# Is there a list of formats that GDAL supports range download?

Tags: gdal, satellite

I know that the format Cloud Optmized Geotiff (COG) GDAL driver is able to range download a given image using /vsicurl/. I see that GDAL shows in [its documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html).

I would like to know if there is a list that shows the drivers from this list in the documentation that are able to range download a given raster.

Comment: Range download is a feature of http and the question is more about which file formats can deliver enough metadata for the drivers so they can know what range to download for a certain BBOX. I do not know if any other than OCG (and less efficiently basic TIFF) can do that. Maybe some in-database rasters like GeoPackage or MBTiles.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GDAL documentation for virtual file systems](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#drivers-supporting-virtual-file-systems), many drivers support this capability.

> The full list of these formats can be obtained by looking at the driver marked with ‘v’ when running either `gdalinfo --formats` or `ogrinfo --formats`.

So in a bash shell, the list of drivers with this capability would be the result of `gdalinfo --formats`, filtered to only those that contain a `v` in the capabilities string.